# NSScanner return range of text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a string that where I would like to extract a substring.

The text looks like this:

```
commentText=Hi+there%21&x=28&y=22
```

I would like to extract everything from the first = to the first &x

So the resulting text would simply be:

```
Hi there
```

*I know I'll have to escape the text after I get it isolated

Thanks!

Comment: removed tag 'xcode' http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
NSString *result = nil;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: commentText=Hi+there%21&x=28&y=22];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"=" intoString:nil];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"&" intoString:&result];
```

Comment: That worked! I just had to make a substring since the '=' was still there: result = [result substringFromIndex:1];